# rqt_graph in ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi is it possible to visualize the ROS2 nodes graph using ROS1 rqt_graph package?

I have ROS1 kinetic and ROS2 bouncy installed on my pc.
I tried to run the ROS2 example nodes publisher and subscriber, but I'm not visualizing them in the resulting graph.

I run the following (each command is in a separate terminal)

`$ roscore`

`$ ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --bridge-all-2to1-topics`

`$ ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher publisher_lambda`

`$ ros2 run examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber subscriber_lambda`

`$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph`

The result is a graph where there is the ros bridge connected to the topic used by the ROS2 nodes, but they are not visualized.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302730/rqt_graph-in-ros2/) by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1322 on 2018-09-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the ROS 1 `rqt_graph` will conceptionally not be able to introspect anything from ROS 2. It can only "see" up to the bridge.

Once `rqt` has been ported to ROS 2 (and `rqt_graph`) then you can use that tool to visualize the ROS 2 side of your graph (again the ROS 2 tool won't be able to see any ROS 1 nodes / topics either).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0